# jQuery: CSS Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

How would I use jQuery CSS Selectors to find for instance:

css class name: "Text" which is a div inside of dom object "wrapper"?

Answer (score 6):

$('#wrapper div.Text') or $('#wrapper .Text'), depending on how specific you want to be.

Answer (score 1):

To add to nezroy's answer: $('#wrapper > div.Text') if you only want elements directly inside the wrapper and not all that might be nested inside.

Answer (score 0):

either

```
$('#wraper .text')
```

or

```
$('.text', $('#wraper'))
```

will work well with same results (even tho, i guess the second option is faster)

Comment: Could you tell me why the second option is faster?

Comment: Dunno, that's why i said I GUESS :)